# Html table with data from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a form like this one:

```
<?php
    echo '<tr>
    <td><strong>Kamp</strong></td>
    <td width="80px"><strong>1X2</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Resultat</strong></td></tr>';
    $no = 1;    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['kamp'].'</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="k1" id="k11" value="1" />1<input type="radio" name="k1" id="k1x" value="X" />X<input type="radio" name="k1" id="k12" value="2" />2</td>
            <td><input name="k1r" type="text" id="k1r" placeholder="X-X" /></td>
        </tr>

    ';
    $no++;

}?>
```

And it echo a nice form with 3 rows from my database in the first `<td>`. It is like a betting-game, so I have the mathes in my database. But as it is right now, the user will check the radiobuttons at 3 different mathes, but submit the same, if you understand. How can I make it 3 different inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use counter in my loop

```
$no = 1;    
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['kamp'].'</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="k1_'.$no.'" id="k11_'.$no.'" value="1" />1<input type="radio" name="k1_'.$no.'" id="k1x_'.$no.'" value="X" />X<input type="radio" name="k1_'.$no.'" id="k12_'.$no.'" value="2" />2</td>
            <td><input name="k1r_'.$no.'" type="text" id="k1r_'.$no.'" placeholder="X-X" /></td>
          </tr>
';
$no++;
```

Comment: But i need 3 different radio-button groups, named 'k1', 'k2' and 'k3'. How is that possible in this code?

Answer (score 0):

if you want multiple input fields with the same name you can create an array of input values with brakets

```
<input type="radio" name="k1[]" id="k11" value="1" />
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays for more infomation.